# I need world's .sql or .json file for address table where my columns are country, state, city, street and zip

Tags: php, sql, json, laravel, location

I'm Planning to do a Laravel project where I want world's location like country, state, city, street and zip code. I have searched a lot but cannot find the appropriate one. So is there anyone who do have .sql or .json file for my requirement?

If no one has the file then Please tell be how to handle world's location in my address table.??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any free list for world wide addresses.

There are address validation services like https://www.edq.com/address-verification/ or individual country's postal services (like https://auspost.com.au/business-solutions/data-marketing-services/improve-your-data/address-data/address-validation - however they go through data services companies anyway)

The ecommerce platform Zen Cart (https://www.zen-cart.com/) includes a table of countries, zones and address formats.  Might be an idea to extract that table as a starting point.

Finally, a comprehensive guide to all things international addresses is [FRANK'S COMPULSIVE GUIDE TO POSTAL ADDRESSES](http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/postal/)